# How do I translate a linq query to an extension method chain with lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm using LINQ to Entities and I want to know how do I translate the following query to lambda expression using extension methods.

```
public _Deposito RegresaDepositosBancarios(int id)
        {
            return (from d in context.depositos_bancarios
                    where d.IDDeposito == id
                    select new _Deposito
                    {
                        idDeposito = d.IDDeposito,
                        cantidad = d.Monto,
                        fecha = d.FechaDeposito,
                        aplicado = d.Aplicado

                    }).Single();
        }
```

Notice that I'm returning a _Deposito type, how do I achieve this using extension methods?

I need something like the following:

```
public Persona RegresaPersonaPorNombres(string nombres, string apellidoP, string apellidoM)
        {
            var p = context.personas.Where(x => x.Nombres == nombres &&
                                               x.ApellidoP == apellidoP && 
                                               x.ApellidoM == apellidoM).FirstOrDefault();
            return p;
        }
```

I don't want to return an entity type but a custom type instead

Comment: Extension of what??? Show the classes. And if you will explain the meaning of the extension, you will get better answers.

Comment: @gdoron: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @KendallFrey. I know what extension methods are! thank you...

Comment: @gdoron: Well, your knowledge certainly doesn't manifest itself.

Comment: @KendallFrey I think gdoron misread the question as "how do I use extension methods to effect the translation of this query to a lambda expression".  There's no need to be snippy.

Comment: Didn't find the reason for voting down my question, but i got what i needed

Comment: @JorgeZapata. **I did not downvote**, but look on the mess because the question wasn't clear enough... more than 10 comments teaching me extension methods... **:-)**

Comment: @gdoron certainly I didn't express myself correctly leading to a discussion, however your comments also helped me to get a better idea of the subject. Thanks

Comment: @JorgeZapata since the accepted answer is a method chain that uses lambda expressions, not a lambda expression that uses extension methods (and to correct the typing error in the question title), I've changed the question title again.  Let me know if you disapprove.

Comment: @phoog looks correct for me :), thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how this would be written with extension methods, but you really should not need to worry as they are both the same thing.

```
return context.depositos_bancarios
    .Where(d=>d.IDDeposito == id)
    .Select(d=>new _Deposito
                {
                    idDeposito = d.IDDeposito,
                    cantidad = d.Monto,
                    fecha = d.FechaDeposito,
                    aplicado = d.Aplicado

                })
    .Single();
```

An interesting side note: I could have used a `d=>` in the `Where` and then an `e=>` in the `Select`. Whereas, the d propogates down throughout the phrase. The only way to reset it would be to use a [let phrase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx). This has nothing to do with the direct question, but I just thought it interesting and wanted to point it out :)

Comment: @gdoron the methods in this linq method chain are extension methods.

Comment: @gdoron You really should look up what an extension method is. How do you think the chaining works in this case? Take a look at the select method...not the this keyword on the first parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743.aspx

Comment: It is two extension methods; Where and Select. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx

Comment: Perfect, that's what I'm talking about, glad you got it. Thanks

Comment: I understood he wants to write an extension method what will do it for him. maybe you're right.

Comment: @KendallFrey actually, it's three extension methods: Where, Select, and Single.

Comment: @gdoron yes, I think it's "how do I translate to (lambda using extension methods)?" not "how do I translate (to lambda) using extension methods?"

Comment: @phoog: Oops, missed the little line at the bottom.

Comment: I updated my answer to have what I feel is an interesting tidbit if you care :)...It doesnt really add to the answer :p

Comment: @JustinPihony that is an interesting tidbit. It's not entirely irrelevant to the question, as it points out that the transformation changes the variable scoping, which needs to be taken into account when translating between the two syntaxes.